# Start program as user on Windows Server 2016 boot (allowing access to program via RDP)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, service

I'd like to set up a non-domain'd Windows Server 2016 to automatically start a specific graphical application as a specific user at boot such that it is always running -- even after a reboot -- and always accessible by anyone who RDP's into the server as that user.

This answer seems to be close to what I want and might do for our use case:

> I just wanted to add a notice that this is still a suitable way to create a non-authenticated "kiosk machine", if you also add
>
> ```
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
> "ForceAutoLogon"="1"
> ```
>
> for logging the user automatically in right after logout. If your user is on Domain Guests group the profile will be automatically deleted on every logoff and a fresh profile created based on default profile. You could also change the shell for example if you want to launch a web browser instead of the default explorer.exe. Then, closing browser window will cause deletion of all cache and browsing history.
>
> ```
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
> "Shell"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
> ```
>
> https://serverfault.com/a/840559/968545

It *sounds* to me like that's suggesting this will allow us to set up the server such that it always logs in 1 particular user and starts the program defined by `Shell` in a kiosk mode. And while I do really like the idea of a kiosk mode in this case, the fact that this method would limit us to achieving the desired behavior with only 1 user makes it feel like it's not the right route. It seems to me that we would ideally be able to have any arbitrary number of programs launch via different users such that you could RDP into any of those user accounts and access their launched-at-boot programs.

I appreciate any direction! Most of my background is in linux server management; my Windows experience is limited to basically some light usage during school

Comment: `always accessible by anyone who RDP's into the server as that user.` So you want to start an console application, and have any account access that graphical UI when they logon? That will not work.  This will only work with one session, but even then it would require elevated privileges to connect to that session. It sounds like you are attempting to use an application in a fundamentally different way than it was deliberately designed.

Comment: Also Windows will do most of this without those tools now. For example, if you use `shutdown /r /g` "Full shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is rebooted, if Automatic Restart Sign-On is enabled, automatically sign in and lock last interactive user.". It does this by saving the logged on users credentials the same way that SysInternals Autologon does, and Windows can also be optionally configured to restart all of the applications that were open. That was added to prevent people from having to logon to an endpoint and restart an app after security updates.